# Expirable LRU cache

Tags: python, cache

The requirements are:

- evict any expired items
- find the items with the lowest priority and evict the least recently used one

Any feedback would be appreciated.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class LRUCache:
    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.cache = OrderedDict() 
        self.timer = 0 

    def get(self, key):
        if key in self.cache:
            value, timestamp = self.cache[key]
            if self.timer - timestamp <= value[1]: 
                self.cache.pop(key)
                self.cache[key] = (value, self.timer) 
                self.timer += 1
                return value[0]
            else:
                self.cache.pop(key)
        return -1

    def put(self, key, value, ttl):
        if key in self.cache:
            self.cache.pop(key)
        elif len(self.cache) >= self.capacity:
            self.cleanup(ttl)

        if len(self.cache) >= self.capacity:
            self.cache.popitem(last=False)

        self.cache[key] = ((value, ttl), self.timer)
        self.timer += 1

    def cleanup(self, ttl):
        expired_keys = []
        min_priority = float('inf')
        print(min_priority)
        min_priority_keys = []

        for key, ((priority, ttl), timestamp) in self.cache.items():
            print(key, ((priority, ttl), timestamp), self.timer)
            if self.timer - timestamp > ttl:
                expired_keys.append(key)

            if priority < min_priority:
                min_priority = priority
                min_priority_keys = [key]
            elif priority == min_priority:
                min_priority_keys.append(key)

        if expired_keys:
            for key in expired_keys:
                self.cache.pop(key)
        else:
            min_lru = float('inf')
            min_lru_key = None

            for key, (_, timestamp) in self.cache.items():
                if key in min_priority_keys and timestamp < min_lru:
                    min_lru = timestamp
                    min_lru_key = key

            if min_lru_key is not None:
                self.cache.pop(min_lru_key)


# Usage example:
cache = LRUCache(3)
cache.put("key1", 3, 2)
cache.put("key2", 5, 20)
cache.put("key3", 1, 20)
cache.put("key4", 10, 29)


# # After updating the timer, retrieve items, and expired items will be automatically removed
print(cache.get("key1")) # is expired
cache.put("key5", 5, 29)
print(cache.get("key2")) # has higher priority than key3
print(cache.get("key3")) # was evicted to make space for key 5 -> (key4, key5, key2)
```

Answer (score 2):

## name

A [lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache)
with expiry, nice! I like the requirements.

Calling it `LRUCache` seems to invite confusion with the well-known
functools decorator, at least during telephone discussions.
Consider calling it a "timed LRU cache",
highlighting the TTL field.

Consider also offering its functionality via a @decorator.

---

## default TTL

Time to live is a mandatory argument on each `.put()` call.

```
    def __init__(self, capacity):
```

Consider appending a `... , default_ttl: float):` argument to the `__init__` ctor,
which would let the `.put()` TTL be optional.

Type hints in app-level code are strictly optional,
added when the application author feels they are helpful.
But a library author has a broader set of responsibilities to diverse callers.
It would be a kindness to type hint this code so `mypy` lints cleanly.
Notice that PEP 484 offers an "int TTLs are fine in a float context" shortcut.
The capacity clearly should be an `int`.

I have maintained a fair amount of
[redis](https://pypi.org/project/redis) client application code,
which inevitably stores a bunch of keys with some TTL value.
In a given app the TTL might be constant or it might vary across key categories.
I can tell you that it is *much* easier for a maintainer to gain an understanding
of what is going on, what invariants will hold, if TTL behavior is "boring".
Often this would be done by defining a MANIFEST_CONSTANT
which conventionally appears in each request.
It would be very helpful if you offer a "path of least resistance"
to support this common need of authors, for clearly expressing their intent,
and of maintainers, for rapidly understanding app behavior.

---

## LRU on update

```
    def put(self, key, value, ttl):
        if key in self.cache:
            self.cache.pop(key)
```

This is perfectly nice; it is an interesting design choice.
As a library user it wouldn't be obvious to me
that storing X under key1 and later updating it to Y
would make key1 least recently used.
It could go either way.
Just add a docstring that describes the behavior.
(Note that, since you elected to call it public `cache`
rather than private `_cache`, caller could always `.pop()` if desired.)

The rest of the logic is very clear, thank you.

And then we come to this:

```
        self.timer += 1
```

What? Time to live does not have units of wallclock seconds?!?
Ok, we *really* need to have a talk about writing """docstrings""".
It is necessary to tell callers what your library does.
In this case, what seemed to be clear names weren't.
The naming obscures the actual behavior.
The semantics feels a bit like "each router hop shall decrement the IP TTL field",
event-based rather than time-based.

---

## tidy up before review

```
    def cleanup(self, ttl):
        ...
        print(min_priority)
            ...
            print(key, ((priority, ttl), timestamp), self.timer)
```

You're requesting review prior to merging down to `main`.
This is the right time to delete debug logging and chatty print() statements.

If you need instrumentation, consider incrementing counters instead.

---

## time complexity

After a warmup period, typically every .put() will do a .cleanup().

```
        for key, ((priority, ttl), timestamp) in self.cache.items():
```

Ummm, we linearly scan the *entire* cache? Every time?!?

The `cleanup` docstring really needs to warn about that.
And / or we need to find a way to bail early, or amortize the cost.
For example we might admit a "double capacity" internal memory footprint,
and let .get() discard old entries which should not be externally visible.
That would reduce the need for every single put to do a full cleanup.

I was really expecting to find a TTL
[priority queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html)
at the center of this library.
With capacity C,
that would let you discard K old entries in `K × log(C)` time.

It might be helpful to have a very short `cleanup` which calls a pair of helpers.
Then the docstring for each could explain the
[single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)
being addressed, either expiring old entries in a LRU sense or in a TTL sense.

---

## memory complexity

```
        self.cache[key] = ((value, ttl), self.timer)
```

This is an interesting storage scheme. I like it, feel free to keep it as-is.

But the pair of tuples requires one extra pointer for that one extra tuple.
So an app that is storing small integer keys and values
will pay noticeably more overhead compared to a simpler scheme.

Despite the convenience of certain unpack operations in `cleanup`,
consider converting this to just a single 3-tuple, to save memory.

---

## unit tests

```
print(cache.get("key1")) # is expired
```

Thank you for offering example usage.

This is not a self-evaluating test;
it does not know the right answer.
Rather, it invites a human to eyeball the answer and make a decision.

Please add a proper
[test suite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase).
For example, show the expiration with `self.assertEqual(-1, cache.get("key1"))`.

---

## sentinel

```
    def get(self, key):
        ...
        return -1
```

This is astonishing behavior.

Minimally, describe it in a docstring.

Suppose an app stores integers in the range `-3 .. 3`.
It has no way to distinguish "missing" from a legitimate value.
Consider relying on the usual `sentinel_missing = object()` idiom
to invent a value that caller definitely won't attempt to store.

Or offer an optional `... , default=None):` parameter as other APIs do.
Or `raise KeyError`.

## tuple unpack

```
            value, timestamp = self.cache[key]
```

Rather than use obscure `[0]` / `[1]` subscripts on `value`,
please use the same `((priority, ttl), timestamp)` unpack that `cleanup` does.

---

## invariants

The high level advice from this review is that the source code
really needs to document its behavior.

The class docstring should introduce the concept behind `self.timer`,
distinguishing it from elapsed wallclock time.

Each method docstring should describe
its complexity along with app-level behavior.
Assume a user will cache some thousands of entries,
and that "warmup" behavior before `capacity` is reached
is of relatively little interest.

Invariants of interest to a caller include statements
like "after this call all TTLs will be in [this] range"
or "old stored values have expired after [this] or [that] happens".

---

This library achieves a subset of its design goals.
Scaling and documentation are areas of concern.

I would be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks on this codebase.